# Restful WCF not working when svc and cs files kept under user-created folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, wcf-rest

I created a restfulWCF service using [Restful WCF called MyRESTService](http://www.easywcf.com/five-steps-to-create-a-wcf-rest-service/)
If I dont put my RESTfulWCF under any folder and don't use any namespace it works, but if i use namespace like MyRESTServiceTest.services.RESTfulWCF.ProductRESTService and put my WCF files under a two folders, it doesnt work and gives me error like

The type 'MyRESTService.services.RESTfulWCF.ProductRESTService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.

I created a 2 folders in my project(MyRESTService) services->RESTfulWCF
and put all my WCF files under RESTfulWCF folder in my project. Then my WCF stopped working in my local machine. My WCF name is ProductRESTService
with interface IProductRESTService,ProductRESTService.svc and ProductRESTService.svc.cs and Products.cs files
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GusfO.jpg)

ProductRESTService.svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="MyRESTService.services.RESTfulWCF.ProductRESTService"   %>
```

ProductRESTService.svc.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

namespace MyRESTServiceTest.services.RESTfulWCF.ProductRESTService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "ProductRESTService" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select ProductRESTService.svc or ProductRESTService.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class ProductRESTService : IProductRESTService
    {
        public List<Product> GetProductList()
        {
            return Products.Instance.ProductList;
        }

    }
}
```

Products.cs

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    using System.ServiceModel;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;


    namespace MyRESTServiceTest.services.RESTfulWCF.ProductRESTService
    {
        [DataContract]
        public class Product
        {
            [DataMember]
            public int ProductId { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Name { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string CategoryName { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public int Price { get; set; }
        }

        public partial class Products
        {
           private static readonly Products _instance = new Products();

           private Products() { } 

           public static Products Instance 
           { 
                    get { return _instance; } 
           } 
            public List<Product> ProductList 
            { 
                   get { return products; } 
            } 
            private List<Product> products = new List<Product>() 
            { 
                    new Product() { ProductId = 1, Name = "Product 1", CategoryName = "Category 1", Price=10}, 
                    new Product() { ProductId = 1, Name = "Product 2", CategoryName = "Category 2", Price=5}, 
                    new Product() { ProductId = 1, Name = "Product 3", CategoryName = "Category 3", Price=15}, 
                    new Product() { ProductId = 1, Name = "Product 4", CategoryName = "Category 1", Price=9} 
            }; 
        }
    }
```

IProductService.cs

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;

namespace MyRESTServiceTest.services.RESTfulWCF.ProductRESTService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IProductRESTService" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IProductRESTService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
                                   BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
                                   UriTemplate = "GetProductList/")]
        List<Product> GetProductList();
    }
}
```

Web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service name="MyRESTServiceTest.services.RESTfulWCF.ProductRESTService.ProductRESTService" behaviorConfiguration="serviceBehavior">
            <endpoint address=""
                      binding="webHttpBinding"
                      contract="MyRESTServiceTest.services.RESTfulWCF.ProductRESTService.IProductRESTService"
                      behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
             <host>
       <baseAddresses>
         <add baseAddress="http://localhost:55379/" />
       </baseAddresses>
     </host>

          </service>
   </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="serviceBehavior">
                  <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
                  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>        
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="web">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
          <remove fileExtension="." />
          <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```